# How to force android phone to get Location fixes only from GLONASS and not GPS

Tags: android, gps

hello guys hope you having a nice day

its been alot of time (like 3 years) im working on an app to track most precise locations of a car . but the GPS system has an intentionaly location error fix every few fixes , which is called SA if i remember correctly , and that is the extact oposite of my purpose . but the GLONASS is alot faster , more accurate and doesnt have any issues coming with it . the question is is there any way to get location updates only from GLONASS satelites and not GPS ?

also any tip on how to get more accurate locations is very appreicated.

thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655011/is-it-possible-to-know-my-location-came-from-gps-or-glonass) (a little old and for phones but still actual I hope ?) you have a trick to know were the position comes from.
So maybe you can filter and only process position from GLONASS ?

> GPS and GLONASS satellites are used in combination on devices that
>   support this. To determine if GLONASS satellites were used to
>   determine the location, you can either register a GpsStatusListener or
>   call LocationManager.getGpsStatus(). Call getSatellites() on the
>   GpsStatus object and call getPrn() on each GpsSatellite object in the
>   returned list. If the value is between 65 and 88 and the usedInFix()
>   method returns true the last position was calculated using a GLONASS
>   satellite.

Comment: i know how to filter , but thats waste , so im trying to find some better way

Comment: Well, I agree, but activating only GLONASS highly depends on your device capabilities. For example,  for Leica 1200 and Trimble R8, you just can't switch off GPS.